# SQL Server : Update with Where

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-update

I'm still learning SQL and I've been scavenging the internet for a solution.. For some reason I can't grasp the concept for this query 100%.  I've been on this for a few days and getting no where.  I do apologize in advance, I'm sure this is pretty simple for most of you.

I have a table called `dbo.personnelUDF` and `dbo.personnel` table in the same database.  The `dbo.personnelUDF` references back to `dbo.personnel.personid`. Basically, I need to find the value located in `dbo.personneludf.employee_id_` and update the `dbo.personneludf.active_fueler_ = '1'`

This is what am I'm getting.. what am I doing wrong??

```
UPDATE dbo.PersonnelUDF
SET Active_Fueler_ = '1'
FROM dbo.PersonnelUDF AS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.Personnel ON dbo.Personnel.ObjectID = dbo.PersonnelUDF.ObjectID
WHERE dbo.PersonnelUDF.Employee_ID_ = 123456
```

Error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The multi-part identifier "dbo.PersonnelUDF.ObjectID" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The multi-part identifier "dbo.PersonnelUDF.Employee_ID_" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have aliased the table and then havent used it, you can do the below

```
UPDATE dbo.PersonnelUDF
set Active_Fueler_ = '1'
from dbo.PersonnelUDF INNER JOIN dbo.Personnel
ON dbo.Personnel.ObjectID=dbo.PersonnelUDF.ObjectID
where dbo.PersonnelUDF.Employee_ID_=123456
```

### OR

```
UPDATE A
set Active_Fueler_ = '1'
from dbo.PersonnelUDF AS A INNER JOIN dbo.Personnel
ON dbo.Personnel.ObjectID = A.ObjectID
where A.Employee_ID_=123456
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have aliased PersonnelUDF in the FROM clause "AS a". If you get rid of that, it should work.